# How can we read MDB file in Rails to dump it in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On Ubuntu I am using `dbtools` to read a *.mdb file via terminal commands.

Is there a gem or method so that I can read the MDB file using Rails?

I want to run the same project in Windows.

I want to convert MDB to a SQL file and dump it to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've got everything you need to write such a gem :)

There's nothing but pain on the path where you're headed. My totally unsupported opinion is that your best option is probably JRuby with a JDBC-based MS Access driver or a JDBC/ODBC bridge. That way you have the same toolset on both platforms and avoid a *ton* of other issues -- you just have the "normal" problem of accessing MSAccess from Java, which while complicated is less hard than from MRI Ruby.

Of course SQLite would be a cross-platform option but I'm assuming specific reasons you have to use MSAccess.

If you app's data needs are really simple, you could implement just enough of the behavior you need by wrapping the appropriate mdbtools commands into the appropriate model or mix them in with a custom module. But ow, that's going to hurt and you'll not get any of ActiveRecord, though here that's probably good.

You are in a similar place to anyone using a new NoSQL database -- you'll need to roll your own and you'll be using less AR.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This gem is for READONLY access to MDB files in rails: [activemdb](https://github.com/automatthew/activemdb). I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a different attack.

On your Ubuntu host, load the PostgreSQL drivers and development package, then install the [pg](http://rubygems.org/gems/pg) and [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) gems.

Write some code there to read the MDB file, and use Sequel to directly connect to Postgres over the network and insert the records directly.

Alternates would be to have Sequel write the necessary SQL commands to a file, or use the CSV module to create an intermediate file, which you them import into PostgreSQL, but that's a wasted intermediate step in my mind.

You don't need to do this from Rails; I'd avoid Rails completely as it really doesn't add any value for your task.

If you want to leverage your ActiveRecord knowledge, you can use it apart from Rails, and have it connect to Postgres directly from the Ubuntu system.

Comment: Sequel uses the WIN32OLE library to connect to .mdb files, that means that you cannot connect with this in a non windows machine